Can't inject Emitter into class using Quarkus: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DefinitionException: SRMSG00019: Unable to connect an emitter
I have a class in which I run a check on a schedule using Quartz inside of an Quarkus application.
The result should be send with AMQP using an emitter.
Unfortunately the emitter can not be injected. I don't really understand that since I already inject the emitter in other classes, where it works fine.
I also inject a ConfigMapping, which works fine in the same class.
I use Java 21 and Quarkus 3.17
Here is the problematic class (working class at the end):
package myproject.scheduling;

import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Channel;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Emitter;
import io.quarkus.scheduler.Scheduled;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

import myproject.config.ConnectionChecks;
import myproject.config.Constants.AmqpQueues.Producers;
import myproject.config.Constants.Jobs;
import myproject.models.measurements.ConnectionStatus;
import myproject.scheduling.jobs.ConnectionCheckRunner;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Scheduler {

    @Inject
    @Channel(Producers.MONITORING)
    Emitter<String> emitter;

    @Inject
    ConnectionChecks checks;

    @Scheduled(every = "1s", identity = Jobs.CONNECTION_CHECK)
    void scheduleInternetCheck() {
        List<ConnectionStatus> result = new ConnectionCheckRunner(checks).run();
        result.forEach((entry) -> System.out.println(entry.toLineProtocol()));
        result.forEach((entry) -> emitter.send(entry.toLineProtocol()));
    }
}

Here is the error log:
2024-12-01 22:13:47,731 ERROR [io.qua.sch.com.run.StatusEmitterInvoker] (executor-thread-1) Error occurred while executing task for trigger io.quarkus.quartz.runtime.QuartzSchedulerImpl$QuartzTrigger@7f01115e: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Emitter<java.lang.String> myproject.scheduling.Scheduler.emitter
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:332)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:347)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:874)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:887)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2357)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$MinimalStage.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2948)
    at io.quarkus.scheduler.common.runtime.DefaultInvoker.invoke(DefaultInvoker.java:25)
    at io.quarkus.scheduler.common.runtime.DelegateInvoker.invokeDelegate(DelegateInvoker.java:29)
    at io.quarkus.scheduler.common.runtime.StatusEmitterInvoker.invoke(StatusEmitterInvoker.java:35)
    at io.quarkus.scheduler.common.runtime.DelegateInvoker.invokeDelegate(DelegateInvoker.java:29)
    at io.quarkus.scheduler.common.runtime.DelegateInvoker.invokeComplete(DelegateInvoker.java:36)
    at io.quarkus.scheduler.common.runtime.OffloadingInvoker$2.call(OffloadingInvoker.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.scheduler.common.runtime.OffloadingInvoker$2.call(OffloadingInvoker.java:51)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$4(ContextImpl.java:192)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:270)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$1.execute(ContextImpl.java:221)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:56)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$15.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:642)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2675)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2654)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.runThreadBody(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1627)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1594)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:11)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:11)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Emitter<java.lang.String> myproject.scheduling.Scheduler.emitter
    at myproject.scheduling.Scheduler_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
    at myproject.scheduling.Scheduler_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at myproject.scheduling.Scheduler_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:119)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:38)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
    at io.quarkus.arc.generator.Default_jakarta_enterprise_context_ApplicationScoped_ContextInstances.c3(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.generator.Default_jakarta_enterprise_context_ApplicationScoped_ContextInstances.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getApplicationScopedDelegate(ClientProxies.java:21)
    at myproject.scheduling.Scheduler_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source)
    at myproject.scheduling.Scheduler_ClientProxy.scheduleInternetCheck(Unknown Source)
    at myproject.scheduling.Scheduler_ScheduledInvoker_scheduleInternetCheck_db9533208f2a6decf3d622882f85ce81424bd3a1.invokeBean(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DefinitionException: SRMSG00019: Unable to connect an emitter with the channel `monitoring-producer`
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.extension.ChannelProducer.getEmitter(ChannelProducer.java:225)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.extension.ChannelProducer.produceEmitter(ChannelProducer.java:173)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.extension.ChannelProducer_ProducerMethod_produceEmitter_jRfYFqSs8A2Ams_fdlkwttyVQ3w_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.extension.ChannelProducer_ProducerMethod_produceEmitter_jRfYFqSs8A2Ams_fdlkwttyVQ3w_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.extension.ChannelProducer_ProducerMethod_produceEmitter_jRfYFqSs8A2Ams_fdlkwttyVQ3w_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.extension.ChannelProducer_ProducerMethod_produceEmitter_jRfYFqSs8A2Ams_fdlkwttyVQ3w_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.CurrentInjectionPointProvider.get(CurrentInjectionPointProvider.java:48)
    ... 33 more

Here is an example where I use emitter and it works:
package myproject.rest;

import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Channel;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Emitter;

import myproject.config.Constants.AmqpQueues.Producers;
import myproject.models.measurements.metrics.JobMetric;
import myproject.models.measurements.Data;
import io.smallrye.common.annotation.RunOnVirtualThread;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("data")
@RunOnVirtualThread
public class DataResource extends Resource {

    @Inject
    @Channel(Producers.DATA)
    Emitter<String> emitter;

    @Inject
    @Channel(Producers.MONITORING)
    Emitter<String> metricEmitter;

    @POST
    public Map<String, String> postData(Data data) {
        JobMetric metric = startMetric("api_post_data");
        emitter.send(data.toLineProtocol());
        finishMetric(metric, metricEmitter);
        return getOkResponse("Uploaded data sucessfully");
    }

}


The problem is that Quarkus scheduler extensions (quarkus-scheduler and quarkus-quartz) start before the messaging channels are initialized.
Quarkus scheduler supports delayed start and conditional execution approach as well.
Delayed start
Just set delayed attribute to @Scheduled annotation.
I highly recommend to extract messaging logic to another bean.
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConnectionCheckTask {

    @Inject
    ConnectionChecker checker;

    @Scheduled(every = "1s", identity = Jobs.CONNECTION_CHECK, delayed = "20s")
    void scheduleInternetCheck() {
        checker.check();
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class ConnectionChecker {

    @Inject
    @Channel(Producers.MONITORING)
    Emitter<String> emitter;

    void check() {
        new ConnectionCheckRunner(checks).run().stream()
            .peek((entry) -> Log.debugf("Checking: %s", entry.toLineProtocol()))
            .forEach((entry) -> emitter.send(entry.toLineProtocol()));
    }
}

Guide to delayed start is avaliable here: https://quarkus.io/guides/scheduler-reference#delayed_start
Conditional exection
Create a predicate bean and check availability. The following example checks the smallrye-amqp connector availability.
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConnectionCheckTask {


    @Scheduled(every = "1s", skipExecutionIf = AMQPLivenessPredicate.class, identity = Jobs.CONNECTION_CHECK)
    void scheduleInternetCheck() {
        // do magic
    }
}

@Singleton
public class AMQPLivenessPredicate implements SkipPredicate {

    @Inject
    @Connector(AmqpConnector.CONNECTOR_NAME)
    AmqpConnector amqpConnector;

    boolean test(ScheduledExecution execution) {
        return !amqpConnector.getStartup().isOk(); 
    }
}

BTW, Quarkus has an awesome extension for smallrye-health. Why don't you create a simple health check to monitor your application's internet connection in 5 minutues?
https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-health#creating-your-first-health-check

Thank you a lot. This works. Actually I already had the emitter in the Runner class, but after trying to find the problem I ended up with what you saw.
What do you do in your tests to test this? Do you just delay the tests for a second or so?
I know about the health extension and use it for health requests, but atm I'm rewriting a optimization service that already exists. Therefore I need some structures from the old code.
I work in a setup where the connection is a problem and the business logic needs to when the internet was available, when it's calculating it's results.

*needs to know ...

@JWo What do you really want to test? I think you don't need to test scheduler, it tested on Quarkus side. The only thing you have to test is scheduled task functionality. Because those classes are CDI beans it's fair enough to inject  Scheduler class into your test class and call scheduleInternetCheck() method directly. Smallrye has in-memory connector for testing. https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.3/testing/testing.html
With this connector and Awaitility you can write tests which waits until a message emitted.
